# Command line (CMD, BAT)

Tags: windows, bat, cmd, windows-7

**1.Как можно с клавиатуры считать введенный символ?**

например: есть команда pause, которая ждет нажатия любой клавиши. Хочется сделать выбор, пользователь нажимает, например, пробел - продолжается выполнение пакетного файла, пользователь нажимает esc - прерывается работа пакетного файла.

**2.Как занести данные в переменную?**

например, я получаю версию операционной системы, чтобы далее выполнить команду в зависимости от ее версии. Есть команда, позволяющая получить данные ОС в командном файле,  данные выводятся в STDOUT. Как эти данные можно поместить в переменную для дальнейшего использования в пакетном файле?

Comment: 2. set имя = значение . %имя% извлечь данные. set /? наберите в терминале, появится подробный мануал

Comment: Представте, что вам нужно в переменную присвоить результат выполнения команды:

Dir *.exe | find myfile.exe

на экране появляется только строка содержащей myfile.exe. Как мне эту строку присвоить в переменную str при помощи команды set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте `help for` в cmd.

Там есть примеры.

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (date '/t' ) do echo date = %i
```

выводит на экран `date = 12.09.2012` это пример почти прямо из текста help

Comment: Читал, нет там того, что мне требуется. читал даже полный командный справочник, найденный на просторах интернета.

Comment: Плохо читали.

    for /f "usebackq" %i in (`date '/t'` ) do echo date = %i

выводит на экран

    date = 12.09.2012

это пример почти прямо из текста 

    help for

Прямо скажу, я с bat в винде почти не работаю. Просто интересно стало, что там накручено вместо 

   a=`date`; echo date = $a

в нормальном sh.

Comment: Спасибо.не думал, чтобы присвоить значение переменно потребуется парсить строку через for... 
все же век живи - век учись.

Answer (score 2):

Выполните в командной строке:

```
choice /?
```

p.s. а вообще практически любые проблемы с примерами решений для пакетных файлов решаются поиском по диску `"С" (*.bat, *.cmd)`

Comment: что-то я не подумал, что можно посмотреть готовые решения от микрософта =) спасибо за подсказку. Пойду изучу содержимое папок виндоус и команду чоус...

Answer (score 1):

1. Почитайте про [прерывания (interrupt)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Стандартными средствами консоли тут не обойтись.
2. Это из области работы со [стандартными потоками](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) ОС. Если так интересно, то читайте статью [Using command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), [findstr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true).

Если кратко, то смысл таков: входные данные перенаправляете во внешний (временный) файл из которого вытаскиваете строку при помощи регулярного выражения (см. findstr).

PS. Дабы не изобретать велосипед: [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=VS.85).aspx), JScript/VBscript + [StdIn/StdOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ahda31z(v=vs.84)). Эти штатные инструменты ОС помогут вам.

Answer (score 0):

В батнике примерно следующее:

```
cd C:\
ECHO OFF
chcp 65001
SET /P a="nnn:";
echo %a%
pause
```

Здесь вы считываете определенный текст, далее вам надо определить, что за текст считан и действовать в соответствии с этим.

Comment: Нет, задача занести данные в переменную с STDOUT, а не просто константу присвоить.

Comment: @pincher1519 ключ `/P` именно это и делает. То, что написано справа от знака равенства, становится приглашением ко вводу команды.